# dataset update fails when inserting new row

Tags: sql-server, dataset, dataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

I am inserting a new row into a dataset dsStaff1 via DataAdapter1.Update() method.
I am getting the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'Enabled', table
>   'dbo.tblStaff'; column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has
>   been terminated.

I do have a boolean field 'Enabled' in tblStaff, which is keyword in SQL Server I suppose. It is defaulted to 'True'. I can't really change the name of the field. Is there a work around? OR am I doing something wrong?
PS: I am generating insert, update commands by an sqlcommand builder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a default, then your SQL Command builder must be sending NULL (DBNull.Value) to override the default. The default will apply only if:

- if you don't specify a value for the column in the INSERT
- or if you use the keyword DEFAULT

One of these 2 forms:

```
--Enabled is not mentioned, will use default
INSERT (col1, col1) VALUES (col1, col2) 

--Enabled will use DEFAULT
INSERT (col1, col1, Enabled) VALUES (col1, col2, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So how to solve the problem? I don't know what's in Insert Command as it is generated automatically. Do I need to write the Insert Command explicitly using Sqlcommand parameters? I have pasted my Code at the bottom. It fails on Update

Answer (score 0):

just pass a fixed value to the dataset  in the update parameters

like

```
<asp:Parameter Name="col1" Type="boolean" DefaultValue="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:. It fails on Update.

```
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow

        dr = DsStaff1.Tables(0).NewRow()

        dr.BeginEdit()
        dr.Item("FirstName") = txtName.Text
        dr.Item("LastName") = txtSurname.Text

        dr.Item("StaffID") = txtStaffID.Text
        dr.Item("Enabled") = cbActive.Checked
        dr.EndEdit()
        DsStaff1.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr)

        DataAdapter1.Update(DsStaff1)
```

Also I am using TableMappings in DataAdapter1

```
        DataAdapter1.TableMappings.Add("Table", DsStaff1.Tables("tblStaff").ToString)
```

P.S. Updating and deleting an existing row works fine. It is just inserting a new row doesn't work.